# allow user to edit posts made by others users based on the user role

Tags: query-posts, user-roles, get-posts

I group users by custom user roles so each user groups can view and edit each others CPT . the problem i face now is when i give the user role capabilities related to edit and delete others posts, the be able to edit ALL other users posts and this is not what i want , i want them to only edit and delete posts made by other users in the SAME USER ROLE .

The question:

- i can get the custom user role i made for the current user.
- Now i have the user role , How to get all posts made by users with this user role.
- How to add these capabilities to the current user `edit_others_posts`, `delete_others_posts` for these posts only

Comment: They just need the `edit_others_posts` capability.

Comment: It allow them to edit all posts created by user in any role .. i need to allow them to edit only posts created by users in their role

Answer (score 0):

By giving each role the `edit_others_posts` capability, plus allowing each role to edit only one CPT, you actually getting what you want. no need to check anything about other users capabilities this way.

Maybe what you're missing is having a different capability set for each post type. e.g: if you have CPT called `books` you can create a custom capabilities corresponding only with `books`, `edit_others_books` for instance. It's very easy to code, you can read more about it here:http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/10/meta-capabilities-for-custom-post-types

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: thanks for help ituk , but all users already use the same CPT, it's job listing btw and it has already its own capabilities  , so if i gonna give them this cap `edit_others_job_listing`they will be still able to edit jobs posted by users out their user role

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. lets assume you have 3 CPT's: cpt1, cpt2, and cpt3. you also have 3 user roles except the default wp roles: role1, role2 and role 3. role1 can only creat, edit or delete posts from cpt1, role2 only from cpt2, etc. this apply also for the `edit_others_cpt`. why would a user from role2 for instance be able to edit posts that were written by a role1 user, if the role1 user can only write cpt1 posts?

Comment: No , i have one CPT , and unknown number of user roles because i generate them dynamically based in user meta key , for the purpose of group users .. the point is i want each group of user under the same user role to edit each others job listings

Comment: ahh I get your problem now... let me think.